# How to make the removal of lines from the file?

Tags: c#, winforms

the key is the name of the player, the value is the record (in seconds) there is a code that needs to be improved

I have a file with the name and result of the player (they are written in a different form), on this form, these data are recorded in the dictionary and then the 5 best results are distributed by rating.

Objective: make removal from file

below are my attempts to do this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames()
{
    return File
      .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\D205\Desktop\картинки\results.txt")
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
      .Select(item => item.Split(' '))
      .ToDictionary(items => items[0],
                    items => int.Parse(items[1]));
}


private void updateRatingLabels()
{
    var tops = AllNames()
      .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)                      
      .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal) 
      .Take(5)                                           
      .ToArray();

    if (System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\D205\Desktop\картинки\results.txt").Length >5)
    {

        for (int i = 18; i <= 22; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

        for (int i = 28; i <= 32; ++i)
            Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < tops.Length; ++i)
        {
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 18}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Key;
            Controls.Find($"label{i + 28}", true).First().Text = $"{tops[i].Value / 60}:{tops[i].Value % 60:00}";  //Controls.Find($"label{i + 28}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Value.ToString();
               // remove tops.key


        }

        for (...)
        {
            // set delete from file by key
            // remove these items from the dictionary
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways you can do this...here's one:

```
// @"C:\Users\D205\Desktop\картинки\results.txt"
private static String FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "SomeFile.txt"); 

private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames()
{
    return File
      .ReadLines(FileName)
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
      .Select(item => item.Split(' '))
      .ToDictionary(items => items[0],
                    items => int.Parse(items[1]));
}

private static void WriteNames(Dictionary<string, int> AllNames)
{
    var lines = AllNames
       .Select(kvp => kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value.ToString())
       .ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines(FileName, lines);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var top5 = AllNames()
       .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)
      .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
      .Take(5);

    var tops = top5.ToArray();

    // ... your existing code to work with "tops" ...

    // write out the new file
    Dictionary<string, int> top5dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach(var pair in top5)
    {
        top5dict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    WriteNames(top5dict);
}
```

Comment: Of course, thanks, but the code should have been removed not from 1-5 places, but after 5 places (that is, 6, etc.)

Comment: So you want your resulting file to only have the top 5 in it?

Comment: yes))))I want the top 5 to remain and that after 5 places (6.7, etc.) were removed

Comment: Fixed to only write back out the top 5.

Comment: damn) not so! you have to remove 6 places, etc., and from 1-5 places, they are already saved. I need to remove 6 places from the file that is not shown in the rating!

Comment: That "removes" places by only writing out the top 5.  All other entries will be deleted in the resulting file.   I'm not understanding what you're asking for...

Comment: sorry)I thought it was not the deletion) and when checked it did not work) it is my cant) I just erased the letter one) thank you huge

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a File.WriteAllLines with the data from the dictionary where you removed the items. So you simply have to overwrite the old file.

Comment: please write this in code,because i don't  understand

Comment: especially where there is a comment it needs to be written, because I do not know how!

Comment: or if it is incorrectly written to me then redo the main thing so that it works

Comment: please rewrite this file